# HAProxy logging to syslog

Tags: logging, haproxy, syslog, rsyslog

I installed HAProxy 1.5 via apt-get on ubuntu 14.04 via `ppa:vbernat/haproxy-1.5` as per this [Debian repository selection tool](http://haproxy.debian.net).

The problem is it logging to `/var/log/syslog` instead of `/var/log/haproxy.log`

The setup is basically the default:

`/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL).
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers kEECDH+aRSA+AES:kRSA+AES:+AES256:RC4-SHA:!kEDH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
```

`/etc/rsyslog.d`

```
# Create an additional socket in haproxy's chroot in order to allow logging via
# /dev/log to chroot'ed HAProxy processes
$AddUnixListenSocket /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log

# Send HAProxy messages to a dedicated logfile
if $programname startswith 'haproxy' then /var/log/haproxy.log
&~
```

Comment: maybe this link help you: http://kvz.io/blog/2010/08/11/haproxy-logging/

Comment: For more detailed logging and exemple: https://serverfault.com/a/1087841/401023

Answer (score 25):

Very tricky. :-)  And here is the trick answer:

Notice the file in `/etc/rsyslog.d` It says to log haproxy into `/var/log/haproxy.log` But this will not take effect without restarting rsyslog:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Answer (score 12):

The default `haproxy.conf` file provides clear instructions under the Global settings - `global`. Here i am copy pasting it for you -

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #
```

In my case, for instance, i am running haproxy in CentOS 6.6, the same syslogd server and had to do the following to log to /var/log/haproxy.log:

1. Add below line to `/etc/rsyslog.d/haproxy.conf` -

   ```
   local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
   ```
2. Enable syslogd logging on server -

```
# Provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: In the last part, in the second step (Enable syslogd logging on server); you change these settings in the file `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. After that, restart rsyslog service:  `service rsyslog restart`

Answer (score 6):

Comment out this line from `/etc/rsyslog.d`

```
# Send HAProxy messages to a dedicated logfile
if $programname startswith 'haproxy' then /var/log/haproxy.log
```

Comment: `/etc/rsyslog.d` is a directory, not a file. I'm not sure about 1.5 vs 1.6 differences on Ubuntu, but file `/etc/rsyslog.d/49-haproxy.conf` exists after install of 1.6. This has the following 3 lines: 

`$AddUnixListenSocket /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log \n if $programname startswith 'haproxy' then /var/log/haproxy.log \n &~` (I added "\n" to denote the new lines)

Answer (score 3):

the main problem is that the chrooted haproxy won't be able to access `/dev/log` and in order to circumvent the issue you can either:

- Enable syslog to listen on the UDP socket (usually on port 514) as described in the other messages
- Create the directory `/var/lib/haproxy/dev` and mount `/dev` with bind option onto `/var/lib/haproxy/dev`

It works either ways.

[edit]

After 3 years something has changed. Haproxy now creates a file called `/etc/rsyslog.d/49-haproxy`. One of the lines in the file is:

`$AddUnixListenSocket /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log`.

In this case, the chroot environment can use `/dev/log`

Comment: you can also just add a log socket in the chroot. rsyslog can have multiple. (i'd give an example but it's been years)

Comment: This is no longer the case for newer versions of HAProxy, I am running version 1.5.4 with a chrooted configuration but logging to `/dev/log`.

Comment: @Overbryd yes and no. The newer haproxy adds a file in /etc/rsyslog.d, whithe the following statement inside: $AddUnixListenSocket /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log 
I am gonna edit my comment accordingly.