# How can I get haproxy to log to systemd/journald?

Tags: logging, haproxy, systemd, journald

I have a current generation Linux system I'd like to use with haproxy. Journald will happily log stdout from `.service`, and mark the log as coming from that service, but **haproxy doesn't seem to be able to log to stdout**.

What's the simplest and cleanest way to get haproxy to log to systemd/journald?

**Edit**: current configuration is the default:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
```

But there's no `local2` facility since there's no syslog on the local box.

Comment: What distribution and version?

Comment: @GregL CentOS 7 and `haproxy-1.5.4-4.el7_1.1.x86_64`

Comment: And how do you have HAProxy currently configured to log?

Comment: @GregL Added current log settings above

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Systemd has a Unix domain socket you can log to:

```
global
        log /dev/log local0 info
```

Then `systemctl restart haproxy` to make the changes take effect.

Comment: Dang it, I meant to post an answer with just that, but kept forgetting. Glad you found a way.

Comment: @mikemaccana does not create log files for me, but outputs messages to stdout like this `[ALERT] 079/115253 (7) : sendto logger #1 failed: Connection refused (errno=111)`

Comment: @FelikZ Best to ask as a separate question. Sounds like the systemd socket file doesn't exist.

Comment: @mikemaccana it is actually the answer. I am running that in docker and by default no logging service running

Comment: This will not work if you're using a chrooted environment.

Comment: If you are running haproxy in a chroot environment (default on Debian and derived distributions such as Ubuntu), then you must bind mount `/dev/log` into `/var/lib/haproxy/dev/log`.  This can be done with a systemd mount unit file, which is set to run `Before=` haproxy starts.  You can bind mount this over an empty file (create with touch etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This answer goes for those struggling.
haproxy_global.cfg =>

```
global
    log                 127.0.0.1:514 local0

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    log-format              "%ci:%cp [%tr] %ft %b/%s %TR/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Ta %ST %B %CC %CS %tsc %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq %hr %hs %{+Q}r"
```

/etc/rsyslog.d/haproxy.conf =>

```
    # Collect log with UDP
    $ModLoad imudp
    $UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
    $UDPServerRun 514

    $AddUnixListenSocket /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log
    # Send HAProxy messages to a dedicated logfile
    :programname, startswith, "haproxy" {
      /var/log/haproxy/haproxy.log
      stop
    }
```

/etc/logrotate.d/haproxy =>

```
  /var/log/haproxy/haproxy.log {
      missingok
      notifempty
      sharedscripts
      rotate 14
      daily
      compress
      postrotate
          reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
      endscript
  }
```